# Dart - Get current type of the class

Tags: class, dart, extends

I would like to create a class and refer to the *"type of the current class"*.

So for example in this small snippet, I create a class `A` which has `.child`.

As it is written, the type of `.child` (`A?`) is *"hardcoded"*, what I mean is, if I create `B` that extends `A`, `.child` will be of type `A?`. I would like it to automatically be `B?` *"because the current class is `B`"*.

```dart
class A {
  A? child;
}

class B extends A {
  
}

B? f(B b) {
  return b.child;
}
```

As it is right now, it shows the error

```
line 10 • A value of type 'A?' can't be returned from the function 'f' because it has a return type of 'B?'.
```

[image]

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use generics and borrow the [curiously-recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) from C++ so that the base class knows the derived class's type:

```dart
class A<Derived extends A<Derived>> {
  Derived? child;
}

class B extends A<B> {
}
```

Alternatively you could make `A` an abstract class and have `B` override `child`:

```dart
abstract class A {
  A? get child;
}

class B extends A {
  @override
  B? child;
}
```

If `A` needs a setter for `child`, you can use `covariant` to appease static analysis and allow the setter's value to be checked at runtime:

```dart
abstract class A {
  A? get child;
  set child(A? value);
}

class B extends A {
  @override
  covariant B? child;
}
```